# Prevent background scrolling with dragging on tablet or mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am looking for a solution to prevent the background from moving on safari. I try adding `touch-action: none !important;` in CSS file. also, I try `pointer-events: none;`.
the problem solved on chrome. but in firefox and safari still, the background is draggable.
I the following you see my code:

```css
.img {
    background: url("https://dummyimage.com/1920x1080/000/fff") no-repeat center center scroll;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-position: center center;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
    overflow: hidden !important;
    touch-action: none !important;
  height: 100%;
  background-attachment: fixed;
pointer-events:none;
  }
  
  html {
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
  font-family: 'Source Sans Pro';
  font-weight: 300;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-TX8t27EcRE3e/ihU7zmQxVncDAy5uIKz4rEkgIXeMed4M0jlfIDPvg6uqKI2xXr2" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <title>Hello, world!</title>
  </head>
  <body>


<div class="img"></div>
    
   
<nav style="opacity: 1;" class="navbar fixed-bottom navbar-expand-sm navbar-light bg-danger justify-content-sm-center"><center>
                    <h1 class="my-2 pt-2 text-light">Coming Soon!</h1>
              </center>
            </nav>


 



    <!-- Optional JavaScript; choose one of the two! -->

    <!-- Option 1: jQuery and Bootstrap Bundle (includes Popper) -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ho+j7jyWK8fNQe+A12Hb8AhRq26LrZ/JpcUGGOn+Y7RsweNrtN/tE3MoK7ZeZDyx" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <!-- Option 2: jQuery, Popper.js, and Bootstrap JS
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.1/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-9/reFTGAW83EW2RDu2S0VKaIzap3H66lZH81PoYlFhbGU+6BZp6G7niu735Sk7lN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-w1Q4orYjBQndcko6MimVbzY0tgp4pWB4lZ7lr30WKz0vr/aWKhXdBNmNb5D92v7s" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    -->
  </body>
</html>
```

while you open the result page on tablet or Safari on mobile, while you drag your finger up and down the navbar stays fixed but the background image moving.  I am looking for a solution to make this background fix on tablet and mobile. Please give me some tips.

Comment: Have you tried this CSS on the `body` element: `background-attachment:fixed;`?

Comment: No! still I have the same problem. the nav section remains fixed since I use fixed-bottom but the background image still moving.